# Google map javascript disable google logo link

Tags: javascript, android, maps, graphical-logo

I am using Google Maps V3 javascript API in a mobile app. A Google logo appears in the bottom left corner of the map, if it is pressed in Android it launches the Map application, I want to avoid this. I have seen apps (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.comex.bizi&hl=en) where the logo is grayed out and disabled, this is what I need but I don't how to do it.

Anyone knwos how?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I may be very wrong here but I think it's a licensing issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to purchase the business license to do anything like this.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

> 9.4 Attribution. (a) Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain
>   names, and other distinctive brand features of Google, its partners,
>   or other third party rights holders of content indexed by Google. When
>   Google provides this attribution, you must display it as provided
>   through the Service or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation and
>   may not delete or in any manner alter these trade names, trademarks,
>   service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand
>   features.
>
> (b) You agree to include and display the "powered by Google"
>   attribution (and/or any other attribution(s) required by Google as
>   described in the Maps APIs Documentation) conspicuously on the page,
>   in close proximity and adjacent to the Service search box and Google
>   search results. If you use the standard Google search control, or the
>   standard Google search control form, this attribution will be included
>   automatically, and you agree not to modify or obscure this
>   automatically-generated attribution.

Answer (score 0):

A little trick with simple css ;)

```
/**** google icon image ****/
a[title="Haz clic aquí para visualizar esta zona en Google Maps"] {
   display: none !important;
},

/*** termns of use ****/
a[href="http://www.google.com/intl/es-ES_US/help/terms_maps.html"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Anyway, as is mentioned in the previoos answer ... u should't use this trick or any other to hide the Google Logo icon and others.